# 2 x IP on same subnet issue

Tags: networking, server

I have an Ubuntu server (DELL R320) going with two NICs.

eth0 & eth1 is connected on same Subnet 192.168.10.0/24

eth0 is connected to SW1 with IP 192.168.10.15 and the GW is 192.168.10.1/24

eth1  is connected to SW2 with IP 192.168.10.16 (without GW IP assignment)

SW1 and SW2 is linked with HSRP on same subnet.

eth0 can be reachable and no problem but eth1 is not up "reachable from eth0 but not reachable from switches"

Answer (score 0):

You switches may have IP addresses on other subnet. eth1 is not set default gateway so it cannot reach the switches. You can add a static route for the eth1 in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.10.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
up route add -net 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1
```

Restart networking service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```